# Making a form a little seethrough

Tags: c#, winforms

I was just wondering is there much way to make a form that is a little seethrough? what I have based this idea of is the windows 10 taskbar, it is black and dark but with an edge of seethrough if you look closely, is there a way to make my form anything like that? I have tried so many posts but none have helped me so far, I have messed round with a few settings also but unable to do anything except for making it totallty invisible. Can anyone give me any tips on this?

My app is a winform coded in c#

Comment: Are you looking for [opacity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/czke9azk.aspx)?

Comment: Set `Form.Opacity` to a floating point value between 0.0 (completely transparent) and 1.0 (fully opaque). This is so mind-bendingly obvious that I can't even find a duplicate question. If you've already tried that and it's *not* the effect you want, you'll need to provide us with more details.

Comment: Windows supports three kinds of window transparency effects.  Two of them, opacity and color-keying are readily supported in Winforms through the Opacity and TransparencyKey properties.  But you like the third one, per-pixel alpha blending.  Easy to get going with a wee bit of pinvoke, but you'll discover that all of the controls in the toolbox stop working.  They depend on immediate-mode rendering, exposed by the Paint event.  No more paint events.  The taskbar is done with Direct2D, a library like Eto.Forms wraps it.  Or use WPF, it uses retained mode by default.